# JPA select new constructor cause additional selects

Tags: hibernate, jpa, constructor, left-join, jpql

I have a complex JPA/Hibernate problem.
I have two entities A and B. A references B, but this relationship is not required.

```
public class A {

@JoinColumn(name = "b_id", referencedColumnName = "b_id")
@OneToOne
private B b;

}
```

I write `SELECT NEW dto(a.b) FROM A a` this generates inner join, which isn't good for me, because a.b can be null and I want all of the A entites. So I rewrite my query like this: `SELECT NEW dto(b) FROM A a LEFT JOIN B b` We have to use alias (b) to prevent inner join and get only the outer join. Ok I get all line, but I get extra queries, Hibernate generates SELECT queries for all of B entities. Why, how can I stop this, I use left join, because I want only one query.

**Edit:**

The same problem with inner joins. If use `SELECT NEW dto(a.b) FROM A a` additional `SELECT b FROM B b WHERE b.id = ?` occures, but if I call `SELECT NEW dto(a.b.id) FROM A a` there isn't additional select for B entites.

**Edit2:**

This is exactly same as my problem: [Same problem, without possible solution.](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?t=964901)

Because I don't load the parent object itself, Hibernate doesn't load eagerly B...

Comment: If your query selects a.b, and b is null, what's the point? Do you really want to pass null to the DTO constructor? How is B defined? What are the extra queries?

Comment: Yes, my DTO gets null if b is null. B doesn't references to A. I also need these A entities from the database, which don't have B reference. The extra queries are SELECT ... FROM B b WHERE b.id = ?

Comment: What happens if you just `select b from ...`, and explicitely call your DTO constructor in a loop? I would do this anyway, which would allow for refactoring and just cost 2 lines of trivial Java code.

Comment: If I understand well what did you say, so do you think I have to call explicitly `List l = em.CreateQuery("select b from...").getResultList()` and do a for loop like this: `for (A a : myAList) { B b = findBFromListById(l, a.bId); Dto d = new Dto(a.id, b) }`

Comment: No. Your query is `select b from...`. There is no way such a query returns a `List<A>`. It will return a `List<B>` So the for loop will be `for (B b : listOfBs) {listOfDtos.add(new Dto(b));}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I know what was caused the problem, and I also know the solution.

The *partially* **solution** is to use  hibernate's `setResultTransformer` method. Unfortunatelly JPA doesn't support it...

Answer (score 1):

you want the Bs referenced from A and since you are using hql:

```
SELECT NEW dto(b) FROM A a LEFT JOIN a.b b
```

Comment: I use LEFT JOIN. If I try to use LEFT JOIN FETCH I got this error: "org.hibernate.QueryException: query specified join fetching, but the owner of the fetched association was not present in the select list"

Now I am lost...

Comment: right `LEFT JOIN FECTH` means eager fetch me the reference to B, this is only useful if you are selcting a's. I'll take it out. does the first query do what you want`?

Comment: Yes first query does what I want, but It does additional Selects for Bs.

I edited the question and the link under Edit2 contains a better example of my problame. The bad news is it is impossible since 2006. And I think now the best solution is just put b.id and columns of b which is needed to my DTO, but if anyone has a better solution I have time to listen or read it. :)